# attach dependent jar with project jar in linux

Tags: java, linux, jar, javafx-2, executable-jar

I am trying to run a jar file on linux of swing project using JavaFX . I have installed JRE7 on linux .

My project jar is using two jars: **jfxrt.jar** and **lucene.jar** . I have copied the jars to */home/projectdir/lib/* and also set the classpath by following command

```
 export CLASS PATH=/home/projectdir/lib/jarfilename.jar
```

but I am still getting an error while running my project jar with the help of following command:

```
 java -jar projectjar.jar
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have a typo in enviroment variable: it should be CLASSPATH (without space in the middle).
Also you will need to put both jars:

```
export CLASSPATH=/home/projectdir/lib/jfxrt.jar:/home/projectdir/lib/lucene.jar:projectjar.jar
```

or better use relative paths:

```
export CLASSPATH=lib/jfxrt.jar:lib/lucene.jar:projectjar.jar
```

But you must use main class name, not -jar, as pointed out in another answer.

Comment: its exporting single jar but not multiple jar my dear

Comment: I updated the answer, does it work now? I don't really understand what you mean by "exporting a single jar"

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, the classpath settings are ignored when using the -jar option. Use the -cp option and specify the main class on the command line.

From the documentation:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html#jar

> -jar
>
> Execute a program encapsulated in a JAR file. The first argument is the name of a JAR file instead of a startup class name. In order
>   for this option to work, the manifest of the JAR file must contain a
>   line of the form Main-Class: classname. Here, classname identifies the
>   class having the public static void main(String[] args) method that
>   serves as your application's starting point. See the Jar tool
>   reference page and the Jar trail of the Java Tutorial for information
>   about working with Jar files and Jar-file manifests.   When you use
>   this option, the JAR file is the source of all user classes, and other
>   user class path settings are ignored.

Comment: that will become my number one reason to never use -jar (not that I have ever used it much!)